# Not able to read csv, error: List index out of range

Tags: csv, jupyter-lab, anaconda3, windows-11

It seems like my excel in the format of a csv-file is not properly read as a csv-file in jupyterlab. I have the same code as all of my classmates, but they do not get any error. Could there be something wrong in my excel-settings, or is there mainly a problem with my code?

**  This is my code:**
Use_raw = pd.read_csv("U15_US_2021.csv", header=3, index_col=1, na_values='---').drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
Use=Use_raw.iloc[0:17,0:15].fillna(0)
ValueAdded=Use_raw.iloc[18:22,0:15].fillna(0)
FinalDemand=Use_raw.iloc[0:17,16:21].fillna(0)

```
Supply_raw = pd.read_csv('S15_US_2021.csv', header=3, index_col=1,na_values='---')
Supply=Supply_raw.iloc[0:17,1:16].fillna(0)
```

### **The error:**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 Use_raw = pd.read_csv("U15_US_2021.csv", header=3, index_col=1, na_values='---    ').drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
  2 Use=Use_raw.iloc[0:17,0:15].fillna(0) 
  3 ValueAdded=Use_raw.iloc[18:22,0:15].fillna(0) 

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.    <locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
209     else:
210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
326     warnings.warn(
327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
328         FutureWarning,
329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:950, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
936     dialect,
937     delimiter,
  (...)
946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
947 )
948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:605, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
602 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
604 # Create the parser.
--> 605 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
607 if chunksize or iterator:
608     return parser

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1442, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1439     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1441 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1442 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1753, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1750     raise ValueError(msg)
   1752 try:
-> 1753     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1754 except Exception:
   1755     if self.handles is not None:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:174, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
164 if self._reader.leading_cols == 0 and is_index_col(
165     self.index_col  # type: ignore[has-type]
166 ):
168     self._name_processed = True
169     (
170         index_names,
171         # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'
172         self.names,  # type: ignore[has-type]
173         self.index_col,
--> 174     ) = self._clean_index_names(
175         # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'
176         self.names,  # type: ignore[has-type]
177         # error: Cannot determine type of 'index_col'
178         self.index_col,  # type: ignore[has-type]
179     )
181     if self.index_names is None:
182         self.index_names = index_names

File ~\anaconda3\envs\IO\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py:999, in ParserBase._clean_index_names(self, columns, index_col)
997             break
998 else:
--> 999     name = cp_cols[c]
   1000     columns.remove(name)
   1001     index_names.append(name)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you `print(pd.read_csv("U15_US_2021.csv").shape)` ?

Comment: If I do anything else, I only get another error message: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 24. I think there is something wring with pythons ability to separate the columns on commas.

Comment: Can you share a sample(_as text_) of your dataset ? Just a few lines. It seems that there is some extra `,` in at least line 4.